# SQLite and react-native

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I am faced of a little problem, I want to use sqlite with react native, I have already followed tutorial but none of them operate.
For example for this tutorial: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

When I have to add the code below to the Podfile:

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'react-native-sqlite-storage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage'
```

And I go to iOS file, then I do `pod update`, I have this:

[image]

Then I continue to follow the tutorial:

I don't have this:

[image]

But this:

[image]

So I need help for these problems.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate react dependencies in the podfile.
Remove this line:

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
```

Then try again with pod update.

Comment: Thank you very much, You fix this problem, however do you know why there is no package SQLite in libraries when I open the file of my project in xcode?

Comment: Did you run pod update and/or pod install? According to the instructions it should be enough and you can just use the library in javascript after that. I can recommend moving to use React Native >0.60 if you can so you don't have to worry about manually installing packages.